# Android memory leak and can I be sure if I really have one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

I'm new to Android (just completed my first class) and am struggling with a memory leak issue that I'm not sure is a real issue or not.  I've taken the sample code for reading the contacts database that can be downloaded via the "download sample" button on the Android Developer site here:

https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html

The app runs fine on its own (API 22 or less due to the READ_CONTACTS permission changes).  I want to use the main activity in the sample in my own app as a child of the main activity to pick a contact and pass back its URI to be used to store some custom contact info.  I'm using startActivityForResult() tied to a menu icon to launch the activity as a child of my main activity.  I've changed very little in the sample code aside from executing finish() when a contact is clicked rather than launching the detail activity in the sample app:

Original:

```
@Override
public void onContactSelected(Uri contactUri) {
    if (isTwoPaneLayout && mContactDetailFragment != null) {
        // If two pane layout then update the detail fragment to show the selected contact
        mContactDetailFragment.setContact(contactUri);
    } else {
        // Otherwise single pane layout, start a new ContactDetailActivity with
        // the contact Uri
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactDetailActivity.class);
        intent.setData(contactUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

New:

```
@Override
public void onContactSelected(Uri contactUri) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    intent.setData(contactUri);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, contactUri.toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

The UI functionality is working fine and I get the URI as expected on the callback.  However, StrictMode is enabled and reports that there is a new instance of the child activity each time I call it.  This doesn't happen in the original app even with multiple orientation changes.  I've tried many things to eliminate this issue in my new app to no avail.  Here's what I've tried so far:

I tried setting the intent flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

I tried forcing garbage collection prior to each new call to the activity:

```
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            {
                System.gc();
            }

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

I removed the fragment definition from the XML layout and replace any existing instance via the FragmentManager:

```
     if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ADDCONTACTSFRAGMENT_TAG) ==  null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.add_contacts_container, new AddContactsFragment(), ADDCONTACTSFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }
```

I read that any listeners not re-initialized to null could cause a leak, so I've attempted to create a member variable for all of them and reset them in the onDestroyView and onDestroy methods of the child activity fragment:

@Override
   public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

```
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.close();
        mCursor = null;
    }

    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    mAdapter = null;

    mLoader = null;

    mContext = null;

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy()");
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(null);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(null);

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(null);

    if (Utils.hasICS()) {
        // This listener added in ICS
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(mSearchItem, null);
    }
    mSearchTerm = null;
    mSearchItem = null;
    mSearchView = null;

    //setListAdapter(null);
    mView = null;

    mOnContactSelectedListener = null;

    mDialogClickListener = null;

    mImageLoader.setPauseWork(false);
    mImageLoader = null;

    if (mAdapterView != null) {
        mAdapterView.setOnItemClickListener(null);
        mClickView.setOnClickListener(null);
        mClickView = null;
        mAdapterView = null;
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroyView()");
}
```

I also found several examples of an unbindDrawables() method that was said to be necessary to remove all the View objects, but it doesn't work for an AdapterView, which this fragment is.  Could this be the problem?

I've used both the Allocation Tracking tab in the Device Monitor and heap analysis via the stand-alone MAT application to verify that there are in fact multiple instances of the child fragment in memory, but I'm not sure at this point if this is really a leak or if garbage collection just won't remove the fragment instances until memory is constrained.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Android library that could help to properly analyse memory leaks: [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

Comment: Thanks, @Ozuf, leakcanary was very easy to implement.  It is confirming that the child activity is leaking.  Unfortunately it doesn't give any details beyond that, so I'm left wondering why my version leaks and the original doesn't.  I think I'll do a diff comparison to see if I introduced something.